# Im trying covert 2 images into ndarrays using openv and using it to train a regression model but I keep getting a Error

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

here is the code I have  Written:(NOTE: image1.jpg and image2.jpg have the same dimensions but are diffrent photos)

```
import cv2,numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
im = cv2.imread("image1.jpg")
im1d = np.reshape(im,(1609200))#reshape to 1d from (596,900,3) because in svm.SVR(X,y), y must =1d  

cdata = cv2.imread('image2.jpg')
rdata = np.reshape(cdata,(596,2700))#reshape to 2d from (596,900,3)because in svm.SVR(X,y),X must =2d  

regr = svm.SVR()
regr.fit(rdata, im1d)
i =regr.predict(rdata)#rdata is a part of training data just wanted to see if the code works 
b = np.reshape(i,(596,900,3))#reshape to 3d so it can be viewed as a photo
cv2.imshow(b)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ Folder\Python\module properties\img.py", line 10, in <module>
    regr.fit(rdata, im1d)
  File "C:\Users\Admin1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 169, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
  File "C:\Users\Admin1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 433, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\Admin1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 831, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Admin1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 262, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [596, 1609200]
```

I think this means rdata and im1d dont have the same number of samples but I dont know how to solve it

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You are supposed to provide a batch of images and their corresponding labels to SVR. Instead you are trying to give it a single image and another image as the label. What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: Im sorry im new to this but  in  `svm.SVR(X, y)`, X is a image of a car and y is line drawn in paint and screenshotted with the same dimensions as X. I expected to output to be the array of the car Image since in `regr.predict(rdata)`  rdata is a image of the line. I thought classification models only need labels like `y = 1`. If this is not how it works is there alternative method or different model which can help me?

Comment: So you are trying to build model that will draw the outlines of images for you?

Comment: Yes my main goal is to make the AI draw the stuff for you like input Image of hand drawn car to give a AI drawn image of a car I know it sounds like something too Ambitious but its a long term goal right now im just trying understand where do I start

Comment: For one thing, you would need a lot more data for this. Probably in the order of hundred thousands. You need those many images and their corresponding outline that you drew in paint. And even with that, I would be very surprised if SVR is capable of doing this. You would need to train a large scale CNN model. And for generation of similar images, it's a completely different problem altogether and you would need to train something like a GAN.

Comment: Yes I am aware that you need a lot more data and a better model for this code I dint care about accuracy just want to solve errors.I will look into CNNs and GAN thank you for the help

Comment: so the error happens in `regr.fit(rdata, im1d)`. I need you to print `rdata.shape` and `im1d.shape`. then, I need you to consider and explain what `regr.fit` does, what data it needs, and what data you just gave it.